# Reading floating points from a file

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, input, file-io

I'm trying to read only floating point numbers from the file below excluding all the names of months and districts in a 2D Array and then printing the 2D Array but not getting the correct output, (The output is zeros and garbage values) please checkout my code and try to help.

[Link to the .txt file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7LawZAwfUJUcTVpWmYxclBuM0k)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  FILE *f=fopen("Monthly_Rainfall_Himachal.txt","r");
  float data[12][12];
  int i,j;
  char newLine[1000];
  fgets(newLine,1000,f);
  char* item;
  fgets(newLine,1000,f);
  while(!feof(f)){
    for(i=0;i<12;i++){
      item=strtok(newLine,"\t");
      for(j=0;j<12;j++){
        item=strtok(NULL,"\t");
        data[i][j]=atof(item);
      }
      fgets(newLine,1000,f);
    }
  }
  for(i=0 ;i<12 ;i++){
    for(j=0 ;j<12 ;j++){
      printf("%.1f\t",data[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're doing a lot of the work that `sscanf` would do for you.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit on how to do it as i'm a complete beginner :)

Comment: Google `scanf example`.

Comment: There are several examples on Stackoverflow. For example, see [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712774/parsing-integer-and-float-values-of-a-text-file-with-sscanf). You can do a search on Stackoverflow for `[c] sscanf text file` or `[c] fscanf text file`. You can use `fscanf` as well, which will parse directly. You can also Google for `sscanf` or `fscanf` usage and find lots of information.

Comment: `strtok(newLine,"\t");` should be `strtok(newLine,"\t\n");`. You need to also consider the newline in your delimiter. Should also be using something like `strtof()` instead of `atof()` for converting floats, their is no error checking for `atof()`.

Comment: what is the output you get?

Comment: The output is zeroes and garbage values

Comment: First test if `FILE *f=fopen("Monthly_Rainfall_Himachal.txt","r");` succeeded.

Comment: I've tested for the succeeding of the fopen and also tried for fscanf, sscanf , but terribly failed in making a successful program, please help me it's urgent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of parsing your line with `strtok()`, you can just read your floating point numbers with [`sscanf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf). Their is also information about using the `%n` specifier, which is helpful when reading input with `sscanf()`.

**Note:** Instead of using `fgets()`/`sscanf()`, you could also read your input directly with `fscanf()`, which is another possible approach.

Here is some example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINESIZE 1000
#define ROWS 12
#define COLS 12

int main(void) {
    double data[ROWS][COLS];
    char line[LINESIZE];
    char *lineptr = NULL;
    int offset, row = 0, col;
    FILE *fptr;

    fptr = fopen("Monthly_Rainfall_Himachal.txt","r");
    if (!fptr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fptr) != NULL && row < ROWS) {
        lineptr = line;
        col = 0;
        while (sscanf(lineptr, "%lf%n", &data[row][col], &offset) == 1 && col < COLS) {
            lineptr += offset;
            col++;
        }
        row++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            printf("%.2f ", data[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(fptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Curious, why the space in `" %lf%n"`? Certainly it is not needed.  A style issue?

Comment: @chux Just something I do whenever I use `scanf()`, `fscanf()`, or `sscanf()`. In this case, I think it can be removed. Thanks for pointing that out :).

Comment: I've tried to use the sample program and also tried fscanf, sscanf both but failed miserably in doing so, please help me on this it's urgent

Comment: THe output is only zeroes and garbage values